# How to get the AWS Cognito User group in Flutter?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, flutter, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am building a mobile application with Flutter and AWS. I am using the AWS Cognito user pool to authenticate users in the app. There are types of users in my app, which is the type `USER` and `ADMIN`. The Admin users are in an ADMIN user group. After the user is authenticated, I want to get the user group's ADMIN to a different view.

How to get the user group in Flutter AWS?

Comment: Are You using AWS Amplify? They have an API for this.

Comment: @ExceptionNotThrownException Yes, I am using Amplify, but I didn't found an API support flutter.

Comment: Indeed I didnt found this in the API. Maybe is it worth to writem them a issue in GitHub? Here the Repo: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter

Comment: This might help - apparently you can read the group from the Id Token: https://github.com/furaiev/amazon-cognito-identity-dart-2/issues/66

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the user group after decoding the accessToken. The token contains `cognito:groups` attribute if the user inside a group

```
 AuthSession authSessions = await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession( options: CognitoSessionOptions(getAWSCredentials: true));

    if(authSessions.isSignedIn) {
      final accessToken = (authSessions as CognitoAuthSession).userPoolTokens?.accessToken;
      print("identityId ==>  ${accessToken}");
    }
```

Docs : https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/access_credentials/q/platform/flutter/

Answer (score 1):

no need to decode the jwt token

```
import 'package:amplify_auth_cognito/amplify_auth_cognito.dart';
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify_flutter.dart';

final session = await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession() as CognitoAuthSession;
AWSResult<CognitoUserPoolTokens, AuthException> userPoolTokensResult = session.userPoolTokensResult;
final groups = userPoolTokensResult.value.idToken.groups;
bool isAdmin = groups.contains('Admin') ? true : false;
```

tested with amplify@1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to get and decode the Jwt Token:

```
dart pub add jwt_decode

import 'package:jwt_decode/jwt_decode.dart';
```

```html
Future<void> fetchUserGroups() async {
  try {
    AuthSession authSessions = await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
        options: CognitoSessionOptions(getAWSCredentials: true));

    if (authSessions.isSignedIn) {
      final accessToken =
          (authSessions as CognitoAuthSession).userPoolTokens?.accessToken;
      Map<String, dynamic> payload = Jwt.parseJwt(accessToken!);

      print(payload);
    }
  } on AuthException catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
  }
```

The output:

```html
D/AWSMobileClient( 3097): Inspecting user state details
D/AWSMobileClient( 3097): hasFederatedToken: true provider: cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_RZyl8shky
D/AWSMobileClient( 3097): Inspecting user state details
D/AWSMobileClient( 3097): hasFederatedToken: true provider: cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_RZyl8shky
D/AWSMobileClient( 3097): waitForSignIn: userState:SIGNED_IN
D/AWSMobileClient( 3097): getCredentials: Validated user is signed-in
I/flutter ( 3097): {sub: c507e235-5752-46h7-af83-a2c05b436d5d, cognito:groups: [reviewers], iss: https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_RZyl8blsy, client_id: rehacmqlfabslccps0mfbf5gg, origin_jti: 2b13ea50-29ba-4f5c-9708-f13d53f5e9a6, event_id: 836061ff-78ae-4c1b-8b97-771188c328c7, token_use: access, scope: aws.cognito.signin.user.admin, auth_time: 1676172290, exp: 1676201666, iat: 1676198066, jti: 6c7f656c-7729-46fc-8312-4448a8d9217a, username: c507e235-5752-46df-af83-w2c05r536d5d}
```

Thanks @Dhanuka